# Is there a way to override the interpretation line with an arbitrary value in ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have looked at the Zebra documentation for ZPL as well as searched here on SO to no avail. My scenario is this, I wish to print a barcode on a label using a Zebra printer and ZPL print language but instead of the interpretation line (the human-readable bit below the barcode) being the human-readable version of the barcode I would like it to be a totally different value, e.g. a persons name.

This is the ZPL II guide I am using for reference: http://www.ypsylon.com/download/ZPLII_Guida.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override the text that prints as part of the interpretation line (aka human readable), however you can turn the interpretation line off and add second text field:

```
^XA
^BY3,3,146^FT52,166^BCN,,N,N
^FD>:your_barcode_data_here^FS
^FT241,309^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDyour_text_data_here^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

To turn off the human readable set the 3rd parameter of the ^BC command to N.

You can play with the position of the text field to get the desired effect.

Check page page 89 of the [current manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) for more info.

Comment: Ah, yes that worked perfect. It didn't dawn on me to add an additional field. Thanks!